# Margin Imposition : IEEE RA-L submission

Tags: margins, geometry, ieeetran, ieeeconf

In IEEE RA-L submission, their site says

"Please observe the margins to avoid having the document returned for reformatting"
US Letter first page    Top 60 Left 48 Right 48 Bottom 43 pt
US Letter other pages   Top 57 Left 48 Right 48 Bottom 43 pt

Then, I added  `\usepackage[top=57pt,bottom=43pt,left=48pt,right=48pt]{geometry}` and `\def\IEEEtitletopspace{3pt}` to obey their request. However, they still say the same.
How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\def\IEEEtitletopspace{3pt}
\usepackage[top=57pt,bottom=43pt,left=48pt,right=48pt]{geometry}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                             

\overrideIEEEmargins
```

Comment: I believe ieeeconf is an older version of IEEEconf.  See https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeeconf?lang=en

Comment: You shouldn't need geometry with IEEEconf.  The 10pt option might be a problem, but is probably being ignored antway.  Finally, the top and bottom margins change with [noheadfoot], but I'm not sure which is right.

Comment: The IEEEconf manual doesn't say anything about RA-L having special needs.